# Moving Windows licence to another laptop

Tags: windows-7, windows, license, oem

I have an old laptop (Lenovo e530), which came witn Windows 7 preinstalled. My new laptop arrived with Windows 10 preinstalled (Lenovo e550). I would like to put Windows 7 on my new laptop, too. Can I somehow "move" the Win 7 licence from an old laptop to an new one? Or do I already have a right to install all previous versions of Windows, once I have Windows 10 on it?

None of laptops has any stickers with serial numbers.

Comment: "Can I somehow "move" the Win 7 licence from an old laptop to an new one?" - Nope

Comment: Is there a particular reason you wish to revert to Win7? Software that doesn't work on Win10? Preference?

Comment: I am used to the user interface of Windows 7. It also seems, like Win 10 has too many unwanted program (or features in general), that are distracting. Studying how to hide them would take a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely both your laptops came with OEM licenses which are NON-TRANSFERRABLE. Your only real option is to downgrade your Windows 10 OEM license to a Windows 7 license - which probably won't work, and Microsoft certainly won't help you.

You have 3 options:

1. Try to downgrade to windows 7 and hope that Windows 7 activates per the OEM license baked into the BIOS (it might work!)
2. Purchase a copy of Windows 7, and install it. (With a purchased copy, Microsoft is happy to support you if you run into problems)
3. Embrace Windows 10. Windows 7 will be unsupported by 2020 anyway.

EDIT: Check out this document: https://download.microsoft.com/download/6/8/9/68964284-864d-4a6d-aed9-f2c1f8f23e14/downgrade_rights.pdf

You can downgrade Windows 10 Pro to Windows 7 Pro. Unfortunately not Home. Check your system screen (Windows + Pause keys), do you have Pro or Home?

Comment: I have Windows 10 Home :(